# How to remove an event listener within a class?

Tags: javascript

say that I have the following code:

```
class Sample {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 'something';
    }

    addClickListener(e) { // e is a dom element

        let func = function(e) {
             //what I want to be able to do:
             this.doThing(e);
    }

        e.addEventListener('click', func, false);
    }

    removeClickListener(e) {

        let func = function(e) {
            //what I want to be able to do:
             this.doThing(e);
        }

        e.removeEventListener('click', func, false);
    }

    doThing(p) { 
    //code
    }

}
```

I'd like to be able to refer to a class method from within 'func' and pass it an argument. Making a reference to the class (e.g.  let this = self) does not work as it makes a new version of this each time the function is called and the signature for the event listener changes.

Comment: Well, `func` is two completely separate functions, as they're defined in different scopes.  If you create a single function outside of the `addClickListener` and `removeClickListener` then it will refer to the same thing

Comment: Use `this.func` not `let func` otherwise they're not the same function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove an event listener you need to retain a reference to the function you wish to remove:

```
class Sample {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 'something';
        // I've changed it from "let func" to "this.func" so we retain a reference
        // I also moved it from addClickListener to the constructor so that we
        // don't overwrite our reference when binding more elements to the
        // same function
        this.func = function(e) {
             //what I want to be able to do:
             this.doThing(e); // NOTE: You have another bug here. See comments
        }
    }

    addClickListener(e) { // e is a dom element
        // Replaced "func" with "this.func"
        e.addEventListener('click', this.func, false);
    }

    removeClickListener(e) {

        // Removed the new (unused) function

        // Replaced "func" with "this.func"
        e.removeEventListener('click', this.func, false);
    }

    doThing(p) { 
        //code
    }

}
```

Notice in my comments I said "NOTE: You have another bug here"

When an event listener is called, the context (the `this` variable) is changed to the element that emitted the event. So `this.doThing` will try to call `doThing` on the element `e`!

Also note that `e` the element (the parameter passed to `addClickListener` is ***not*** the same as `e` the event (The parameter passed to `this.func`)

To fix this bug, you'll need to store a reference to the class and use that reference in your function definition:

```
    constructor() {
        this.value = 'something';
        let self = this;
        this.func = function(e) {
             self.doThing(e);
        }
    }
```

Here `self` will ***not*** be overwritten like `this` will, so we can safely use it to reference the class instance

### An even better solution

As I re-read the problem, I realized that your function is literally just calling another function. Therefore, why not pass the function you want to run ultimately to `addEventListener`?

```
class Sample {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 'something';
    }

    addClickListener(e) {
        e.addEventListener('click', this.doThing, false);
    }

    removeClickListener(e) {
        e.removeEventListener('click', this.doThing, false);
    }

    doThing(p) { 
        //code
    }
}
```

Note that this will still have the issue of `this` being replaced by the element calling the event, so within `doThing` you cannot say `this.doOtherThing` to call a second class method. If you wished to do that, then you would need to create a ***bound method***, using JavaScript's `.bind()` method like so:

```
class Sample {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 'something';
        this.boundMethod = this.doThing.bind(this);
    }

    addClickListener(e) {
        e.addEventListener('click', this.boundMethod, false);
    }

    removeClickListener(e) {
        e.removeEventListener('click', this.boundMethod, false);
    }

    doThing(p) {
        //code
        this.doOtherThing(p);
        //more code
    }

    doOtherThing(p) {
        //code
    }
}
```

### One other option

As @evolutionxbox pointed out, you can use arrow functions, as well. This solution would look like so:

```
class Sample {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 'something';
        this.boundMethod = p => { this.doThing(p); };
    }

    addClickListener(e) {
        e.addEventListener('click', this.boundMethod, false);
    }

    removeClickListener(e) {
        e.removeEventListener('click', this.boundMethod, false);
    }

    doThing(p) {
        //code
        this.doOtherThing(p);
        //more code
    }

    doOtherThing(p) {
        //code
    }
}
```

The reason this works is that arrow functions are short-hand for a bound method:

```
x => x + 1;

// Is functionally equivalent to:

(function(x) {
    return x + 1;
}).bind(this);
```

Many people don't realize that arrow functions include the implicit `bind`, and for 90% of use cases it doesn't matter (e.g. `array.map(x => x + 1)` doesn't care about the value of `this`) but within classes this short-hand actually has value, and so it's become a fairly common pattern to use arrow functions in JavaScript classes to avoid overwriting the `this` variable.

Comment: You could use class arrow functions too.

Comment: is it possible to pass 'e' to this.boundMethod as an argument when you call addEventListener?

Comment: @WilliamMartin There are a few different solutions for that. `.bind` accepts more than one parameter so you can bind default values to be passed, but in this case you would need to keep an array or object storing all bound methods. You can also access the element `e` from the event `p` by using `p.target`.